# Where is the Launch Images XCode setting stored?

Tags: ios, xcode

I need to programmatically set the `Launch Images Source` setting in XCode 7 for my app project to `Don't use asset catalogs`. As I will be using a storyboard.

**Important** By "programmatically" I do not mean at runtime. It is actually at build time where I have a script file which runs some code that needs to rearrange the project. I knw you might not like this, but this is the requirement/challenge here.

[image]

I searched in my project's `.plist` file but it seems there is no trace of that setting. Where can I find it? Which file is hosting this setting?

Comment: Why do you need to change the setting when you build? Why would it be different beyond the first time you set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in the `project.pbxproj` file.

There's a `ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_LAUNCHIMAGE_NAME` property that gets set to the name of the file you select.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. The launch images will be stored somewhere in the main bundle and those files can not be changed at run time.

Comment: My mistake for not pointing out, this is not at runtime, please see edited question